# Feature Request: jTab

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jtab, music-notation

We just got a whole bunch of questions migrated from Guitars.  As such, I think we need jTab.  Many of the imported questions relied on it, and are much worse off now ([example](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2801/improving-fretting-hand-strength)).  They could be edited, of course, but that would be a lot of work and their quality would suffer.  jTab will be useful for new questions as well, of course.

Related: [Is there some sort of mark-up for music notation?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/is-there-some-sort-of-mark-up-for-music-notation)

Comment: Very much agree.

Comment: Yep. Were there any other scripts on the old site?

Comment: Yep i was considering going through all my jTabbed answers and replacing the tab, since they make a lot less sense at the moment

Comment: Have left a note on the referenced question, if anyone sees another, please do the same?

Comment: This feature is very much needed, will be very useful :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jTab has been enabled here, so the imported questions shouldn't be broken anymore.

(For the related music notation request, we're still evaluating the options there.)

Comment: Great, thanks :)

Comment: Now that this exists, don't we need to edit the FAQ and editing help? Also, should this be taking effect in the live formatting preview panes? Not having been particularly active on guitars.SE, I'm a bit in the dark on jTab.

Comment: It's a little finicky, or at least it was. There's a bunch of great tutorials located on the main site here: http://jtab.tardate.com/

Comment: Please add a link to jtab on the help page.