# Will a music markup language be added to Music SE? If not, then what is the preferred way of entering standard notation?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

For background reading on this question, see:

- [Is there some sort of mark-up for music notation?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/is-there-some-sort-of-mark-up-for-music-notation)
- [Don't you think this music site just lacks the music itself?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/564/dont-you-think-this-music-site-just-lacks-the-music-itself)

Answer (score 9):

I think that some markup language definitely should be added, and my personal preference would be [Lilypond](http://lilypond.org/).

Comment: This sounds good. I don't use Lilypond yet, but have heard loads of Music.SE users talking about it; sounds like something I should start using. Is it available free of charge?

Comment: @BobBroadley: Yes, that is one if its advantages. Check http://lilypond.org/ for the pure language and http://frescobaldi.org/ for a good IDE.

Comment: Bit of a dumb question I'm sure, but can you play back from Lilypond, too? If not, do you think there would be any interest in having simple MIDI playback functionality for notated music on this site. This would be especially useful for musicians less used to reading conventional notation and "hearing" the music "in-their-head".

Comment: @BobBroadley: Lilypond is just the language and the renderer as I've understood it. Frescobaldi has play back functionality, so it exists in free form. Having playback integrated on the site would be sweet for sure.

Comment: In re to [this question](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/564/dont-you-think-this-music-site-just-lacks-the-music-itself): Lilypond is so feature-rich, and there is existing GPL code out there ([on MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aScore)) that can potentially be used to implement it into the site *and* provide playback functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I usually notate music myself, either on paper and scan it, or using Sibelius (although there are plenty of other types of software available!) I then convert to JPEG and put on the site.

Seems to work pretty well, although it would be good to input music on devices that don't have this software.

As far as I know you can input TAB directly as text.

Comment: TAB is handled through a library called jTab--see that tag on meta for more info.